# How to stack a 'numpy masked array' and a 'numpy array'

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two numpy arrays:

```
A  = [ 186.,  176., 158.,  180.,  186.,  168.,  168.,  164.,  178.,  170.,  189.,  195.,
       172.,  187., 180.,  186.,  185.,  168.,  179.,  178.,  183.,  179.,  170.,  175.]

B = [  -1., 60., 45., 58., 70., 70., 60., 64., 68., 78., 80., 78.,
       66., 74., 84., 85., 75., 60., 71., 67., 88., -1., 70., 60.]
```

I want to stack only Positive values and I don't know how?

I used numpy masked array to mask "**-1**"s  from B

thank you

Comment: " stack only Positive values": What does that mean?  If `C` is the result of the operation you want to do, could you add to your question exactly what `C` would be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you want to stack `a` and `b` for every position where `b>=0`:

```
check = (b>=0)
c = np.vstack((a[check], b[check]))
```

should do the job...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use an unsigned value for it?

```
unsigned int array[2] = {0, 1};
```

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_(computer_science)#value_and_representation

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to stack 1-dimensional arrays and the removal of negative numbers from `B` will make its shape the same as `A`, this should work:

```
np.vstack( (A, B[B >= 0.0]) )
```

Comment: this will must probably give you a `ValueError` since the arrays being stacked have different sizes...

Comment: @SaulloCastro Well it's unclear what the op wants, but yes I see what you mean.  More likely he wants to filter out the elements in A and B if the element in B is negative, as your answer suggests.